# GC9A01 LCD display backlight pwm control

Tags: pwm, lcd, backlight

I am trying to design a simple smartwatch using ESP32 MCU. For the display I am using GC9A01 LCD screen like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002525190127.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.11943ba8EoFHdG&algo_pvid=4e62b3db-88ec-415a-bfc0-ce7073b7b3ad&algo_exp_id=4e62b3db-88ec-415a-bfc0-ce7073b7b3ad-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000020996306937%22%7D). I did get display to work by using prototype board, and now I am designing the PCB myself.

I am not sure if my design for backlight control is correct. I would be using a pin on ESP32 and pwm to control backlight intensity. Here is what I had in mind (based on existing design in prototype board):

[image: BJT PWM driver]

BLK signal is coming from ESP32 and it is supposed to drive backlight on the display. Should this work? Are there some tips what should I be careful about?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the circuit so far, but I see that BLK is connected to VDD and therefore Q1 is on and there will be a flow of current from LEDS to LEDK

Comment: BLK is not connected to VDD. sorry, I should have draw the diagram better. BLK is connected to base of Q1 through R8. When MCU is high the Q1 will be on, otherwise it will be off. One question is do I need pull-down resistor at all?

Comment: @arnisz BLK is not connected to VDD ... look at the junction between R5 and R8

Comment: `do I need pull-down resistor?` ... that should be part of the post, not asked in a comment

Comment: there is no need for a pull down resistor. If there is no current flow to the base of q1 the transistor will be off.

Comment: C10 is superfluous and harmful. It loads the output of the MCU. And if the question were a little more specific, one could answer it, since there are more general things that seem to need clarification. In any case, I would not implement the circuit like this.

Comment: @arnisz C10 does not load the output of MCU. It is not connected to MCU. The circuit is approximately fine for driving LED backlights, unless there are some details we are unaware of.

Comment: Hi, @Marko did it work? I'm thinking of using the same circuit. Is the value of R10 10ohm only? Did you make any changes than the schematic in the question? Thanks.